# How to list rows for a query or display 'no records' using a single query

Tags: php, mysql

How to list records for a query and to display "no records" when no rows returned using a single query?

Currently I am using a `COUNT(*)` query or using `mysql_num_rows()` function; then another query in different result set to list data. Can you tell me if it is possible to accomplish the same with a single query?

Comment: Btw I assume that you are using PHP as you mentioned `mysql_num_rows` If I am wrong please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important:** I assume that the OP uses PHP as (s)he mentions `mysql_num_rows`. And I hope (s)he will tell me if I am wrong.

---

It is your job in PHP to check whether the result is an empty set or not. I don't understand why you have to do another query. Maybe you have to clarify your question.

Here a more complete example:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);

// If if result set contains rows
if(0 == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'no records';
}
else { // Loop over the result set
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       // do whatever you want with the data here
    }
}
```

Reference: [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

---

Even if you don't use PHP, the approach is the same in other languages and there should be similar functions available.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need another query after mysql_num_rows?
why not to just run your query and then check results with mysql_num_rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like following

```
   if (mysql_num_rows ==  '0')
       'No Records'
    else
       //YOUE CODE HERE
```