# PHP: How to take info from MYSQL, make it a variable and place it in a link

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Here's my code - not sure what the issue is?

```
// Make the query:
$query = "SELECT template FROM pages_meta WHERE user_id=$id";  

// RUN THE QUERY
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

$url = 'template';

echo "<link  href=\"$url\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
```

Comment: Issue is that $url is a string, no way related to your $result.

Comment: Please search SO first, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590680/how-to-list-records-for-a-query-and-to-display-no-records-when-no-rows-returned

Comment: There's also a helpful site called php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as said by Jakub, you need to get the data from Mysql and assign to $url.

Do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT template FROM pages_meta WHERE user_id=$id";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<link  href="'. $row['template'] . '" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />';
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

For more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Thanks - tho I tried this code and PHP gave an error about an undefined variable $mysqli which I'm assuming is the database connection? I'm reading your link now, thanks...

Comment: Yes, that is coming from $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

Comment: Awesome! I just replaced the $mysqli with my own database connection in the form of a variable and it worked. Thanks to you and Jakub.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a few issues.

You set the variable `$query`, but use `$q` in `mysqli_query()`. By the way, you shouldn't be using `@`, but rather implement some sort of error handling.

Also, you set `url` to a string value, meaning that it will simply have the value `template`. I believe you should set it to something like `$result[0]->template`, although I'm not completely sure. Try putting the following line in your code and post what it writes out.

`var_dump($result);`

Comment: Have you opened a connection to your database using $dbc?