# List records with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, record

I've created a table (notebook) where I keep user's text. The table is like this one:

```
+------+------------+-------+------+--------+------------------------+
|  id  |  Username  | title | html | public |  create_date           |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1  | sorge13248 | Test  | ...  |  n     |2012-11-24 9:00:00      |
+------+------------+-------+------+--------+------------------------+
```

id = INT(25) A_I NOT NULL
Username = VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL
title = VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL
html = LONGTEXT NOT NULL
public = VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
create_date  = TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
So, I've tried to use this code to list all notebook's record for a user:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "password");
mysql_select_db("notebook", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notebook WHERE Username = '"$username."'", $link);

if(0 == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No notebook was created for this user';
}
else { 
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       // do whatever you want with the data here
    }
}
```

The code has been taken from: [How to list rows for a query or display 'no records' using a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590680/how-to-list-records-for-a-query-and-to-display-no-records-when-no-rows-returne) and I've edited it for use it with my table.

Now, I'm confused, what I must write in "// do whatever you want with the data here" string to list the records?

**EDIT:** Now, I have this code, but Chrome says "HTTP 500 Error, Internal Server Error":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Notebook</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Notebook</h1><br/>
<?=
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "database_username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database_name", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notebook", $link);

// If if result set contains rows
if(0 == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No notebook was created for this user';
}
else { 
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   printf( '%d: &quot;%s&quot; by %s<br />', $row['id'], 
                 htmlspecialchars($row['title']), 
                 htmlspecialchars($row['Username']) );
}
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Where is the error? The MySQL credentials are provide correctly...

Comment: next time put some more efforts to correctly format your question

Comment: what exactly you want to do with the result of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form HTML with whatever you want to display, so your `while` loop would look like, i.e.:

```
while(row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   printf( '%d: &quot;%s&quot; by %s<br />', $row['id'], 
                 htmlspecialchars($row['title']), 
                 htmlspecialchars($row['Username']) );
}
```

which would list all items, like

```
1: "Test" by sorge13248
```

PS: you should always use the same naming convention to avoid problems. in your DB all columns are lowercased, except `Username`).

Answer (score 0):

Example : you can use echo `$row['title']` to print user's note title.

Use `var_dump($row)` to see more information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the use of `mysql_` functions are discouraged since it's gonna be deprecated in the future. Consider to change your code to use either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) API.

You can read more about in the php manual article: [Choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

As stated by the php manual the [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function:

> Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

and then moves to next row until there isn't any other row with results, when the function will return false and your loop is gonna end.

In your particular case, the $row variable would return the following results:

```
$row['id'] = 1;
$row['Username']= "sorge13248"; 
$row['title']= "Test"; 
$row['html']="... &";
$row['public']="n';
$row['create_date']="2012-11-24 9:00:00";
```

So, for `do whatever you want` the tutorial meant that you can return your result by accessing your database using the approach above. Let's say for example that you are interested in echoing the create date from a certain user, you could do the following:

```
echo "<p>User: ".$row['Username']." was created in: ". $row['create_date']</p>";
```

Wich would output the following to the page the script is generating:

```
<p>User: sorge1348 was created in: 2012-11-24 9:00:00</p>
```

I hope it helped, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using mysql_fetch_array as it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

What worked for me was:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notebook;";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{ 

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
       echo $row->username . "<br>";    
    } 
    $result -> free_result();
}
```